# How can we prove LHS equals RHS of this matrix equation?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

If $M$ is a $3 * 3$ matrix and $v$ is $3*1$ vector.

How can we prove $M^{-1}vv' = \frac{(M^{-1}v)(v'M^{-1})}{1 + v'M^{-1}v} (M+vv')$ ?

Comment: My recommendation is to keep the LHS and just manipulate the RHS until everything boils down after multiplication, distribution, cancellation, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you one step to begin with.

Pre-multiply by $M$ to obtain
$$
vv'=\frac{vv'M^{-1}}{1+v'M^{-1}v}(M+vv')\\
vv'=\frac{vv'+vv'M^{-1}vv'}{1+v'M^{-1}v}.
$$
Can you see how to go on from here? A hint is to get rid of the denominator...